# Find Rotation Matrix to align Basis vectors to world coordinate

Tags: 3d

As shown in the attached picture, 4 Points are plotted in the world frame. 3 of them (green colored) defines my plane. With the given 3 green points I can calculate the nominal axis for my plane.
My expectation is to take one of the 3 green points as origin, calculate nominal vector for the plane. Find another 2 basis vectors. After I have 3 basis vectors defining my local frame, I would like to translate and rotate these points.
At the end I would like to make Visualisation where plane is parallel to new local frame.

Here is a function in python that generates/plots the points and plane.

```
class Point:
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
def __init__(self,xx,yy,zz):
    self.x=xx
    self.y=yy
    self.z=zz

def change_x(self,new_value):
    self.x = new_value
def change_y(self,new_value):
    self.y = new_value
def change_z(self,new_value):
    self.z = new_value
def change_xyz(self,v_x,v_y,v_z):
    self.x = v_x
    self.y = v_y
    self.z = v_z
def get_x(self):
    return self.x
def get_y(self):
    return self.y
def get_z(self):
    return self.z

def find_plane_equation_with_distance_error(p1, p2, p3, p_new,bPlot = False):
"p* are the points that are used to define a plane"
p12 = [p2.get_x() - p1.get_x(), p2.get_y() - p1.get_y(), p2.get_z() - p1.get_z()] 
p13 = [p3.get_x() - p1.get_x(), p3.get_y() - p1.get_y(), p3.get_z() - p1.get_z()]
p_temp = np.array([p1.x,p1.y,p1.z])
unit_vector = np.cross(p12,p13)

toBeDivided = np.sqrt(unit_vector[0]*unit_vector[0]+unit_vector[1]*unit_vector[1]+unit_vector[2]*unit_vector[2])
p_error = (unit_vector[0]*(p_new.get_x() - p1.get_x()) + unit_vector[1]*(p_new.get_y() - p1.get_y()) + unit_vector[2]*(p_new.get_z() - p1.get_z()))
#print('Error in plane fit is [before] : ',p_error) 
p_error = p_error / toBeDivided
#print('Error in plane fit is [after] : ',p_error) 
#plot the plane
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(10), range(10))
d = -p_temp.dot(unit_vector)
# calculate corresponding z
z = (-unit_vector[0] * xx - unit_vector[1] * yy - d) * 1. /unit_vector[2]

if(bPlot):
    # plot the surface
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z, alpha=0.2)
    ax.scatter(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z, color='green')
    ax.scatter(p2.x, p2.y, p2.z, color='green')
    ax.scatter(p3.x, p3.y, p3.z, color='green')
    ax.scatter(p_new.x, p_new.y, p_new.z, color='red')
    #plt.show()
return p_error
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaCWO.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Align the points lying on plane parallel to XY or XZ or YZ  world frame

Comment: There is still no question here. What is the exact problem?

Comment: This will almost certainly end up being a duplicate. If you search the site, you should be able to find several questions about how to align a plane with the coordinate axes. For instance, there are at least three related questions in the handy list at right that look like they cover what you’re trying to do in part or in whole.